# Elasticsearch prefix query

Tags: elasticsearch

How to do a prefix search in Elasticsearch ?

For example if I have the following indexed documents:

```
[{
        "id": "1",
        "key": "abc",
        "foo": [1, 2, 3]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "key": "ab",
        "foo": [4]
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "key": "xyz",
        "foo": [9, 10]
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "key": "abcd",
        "foo": [12]
    }
]
```

Now I want to have a query on attribute "key" with value "abcdef".

I expect the following documents to match the query.

| document id | matched | reason |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "1" | YES | "abc" is a prefix of "abcdef" |
| "2" | YES | "ab" is a prefix of "abcdef" |
| "3" | NO | "xyz" is not a prefix of "abcdef" |
| "4" | YES | "abcd" is a prefix of "abcdef" |

Answer (score 1):

Using an [edge-ngram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) (or [token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenfilter.html)) is correct but you should only apply it at search time since the documents already contain the prefixes you're searching.

So you're index settings and mappings should look like this:

```
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "prefix_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "prefix_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "prefix_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 6,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "index": {
      "max_ngram_diff": 10
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "key": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "keyword",
        "search_analyzer": "prefix_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, your search query can look like this:

```
POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "key": "abcdef"
    }
  }
}
```

What is going to happen is that the input token `abcdef` will get tokenized into:

- `ab`
- `abc`
- `abcd`
- `abcde`
- `abcdef`

In the results you'll get:

- The first token will match document 2
- The second token will match document 1
- The third token will match document 4

Answer (score 0):

You can use [edge_ngram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) to query on attribute "key" with value "abcdef"

Adding a working example

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 6,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "max_ngram_diff": 10
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "key": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
   "match":{
     "key":"abcdef"
   }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67419529",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 1.8710749,
        "_source": {
          "id": "4",
          "key": "abcd",
          "foo": [
            12
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67419529",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0498221,
        "_source": {
          "id": "1",
          "key": "abc",
          "foo": [
            1,
            2,
            3
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67419529",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.44839138,
        "_source": {
          "id": "2",
          "key": "ab",
          "foo": [
            4
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Note that it would be better to use that analyzer **only at search time** because you only want to tokenize the input term and not the value in the documents themselves. it's kind of a "reverse" matching where the prefixes are in the document and the full term is in the query (usually it's the other way around)

Comment: @Val yes using the analyzer only at search time makes sense. Thanks !

Comment: @Rahul if the answer helped you to resolve your issue, then please don't forget to accept and upvote the answer as well :-)